# Subtraction with metric prefixes as objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to subtract with prefixes as objects.

Here is my code

```
class Prefix:   
    def __init__(self, m=0, cm=0):

       self.m = m
       self.cm = cm

    def __sub__(self, other):

       centim = self.cm - other.cm
       meter = (self.m - other.m) - abs(centim/100)

       if meter < 1:
          centim = m*100
          meter = 0
          return Prefix(meter, cm)
```

Im trying to subtract in a way which creates a negative centimeter value and take 1m from the meter object such that this is fulfilled

```
Prefix(2, 20) - Prefix(1, 30) == Prefix(0, 90)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, keep in mind that for a given length, everything to the right of the hundreds place goes into `cm`, and everything at it or to its left gets divided by 100, and then goes into `m`.

Given this, we can recast the problem as converting both `Prefix` objects into their full lengths, performing calculations there, and then creating a new `Prefix` from the result:

```
class Prefix:   

    def __init__(self, m=0, cm=0):
        self.m = m
        self.cm = cm

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self_length = self.m * 100 + self.cm
        other_length = other.m * 100 + other.cm

        result_length = self_length - other_length
        result_m, result_cm = divmod(result_length, 100)
        return Prefix(result_m, result_cm)

result = Prefix(2, 20) - Prefix(1, 30)
print(result.m, result.cm)
```

Output:

```
0 90
```

Since we've come this far, we might as well store a "length" and overload `__repr__` to make the result prettier:

```
class Prefix:   

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def __sub__(self, other):       
        result_length = self.length - other.length
        return Prefix(result_length)

    def __repr__(self):
        result_m, result_cm = self.split_up(self.length)
        if result_m > 0:
            return f'{result_m}m {result_cm}cm'
        else:
            return f'{result_cm}cm'

    @staticmethod
    def split_up(length):
        return divmod(length, 100)

Prefix(220) - Prefix(130)
```

Output:

```
90cm
```